# How to insert data to table ,before save create user and use id user for table prime (yii2)?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I have table student and table user that user_id foreign Key table student. I want to save information from student and create user and set id user into user_id in table student

student models:

```
    class Student extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
  public $username;
  public $password;
  public $email;

......

public function rules()
  {
    return [
      [['name', 'lastname', 'tell', 'mobile', 'codemeli', 'birthday' , 'jensiyat', 'address', 'fatherName', 'user_id', 'created'], 'required'],
      [['tell', 'mobile', 'codemeli', 'postcode', 'number', 'user_id', 'salary', 'remove'], 'integer'],
      ['address', 'string'],
      ['pic','file'],
      ['username','string'],
      ['password','string'],
      ['email','string'],
      [['username','password'],'required'],
      ['email','unique'],
      ['email','email'],
      [['created', 'salary', 'postcode'], 'safe'],
      [['name', 'lastname', 'fatherName', 'level'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
      [['birthday'], 'string', 'max' => 10],
      [['number', 'user_id'], 'unique', 'targetAttribute' => ['number', 'user_id'], 'message' => 'The combination of Number and User ID has already been taken.'],
      [['user_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => User::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['user_id' => 'id']],
    ];
  }

.........

public function beforeSave($insert)
  {
    if (parent::beforeSave($insert)) {
      $user = new User;

      $user->username = $this->username;
      $user->email    = $this->email;
      $user->setPassword($this->password);
      $user->generateAuthKey();
      $ret=$user->save();

      $this->user_id  = $user->id;

      return $ret ? $user : null;
    }
  }
```

actionCreate:

```
  public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Student();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            // $model->
            $model->pic = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'pic');
            $username = Yii::$app->request->post('username');
            $password = Yii::$app->request->post('password');
            $email = Yii::$app->request->post('email');
            $model->created = time();
            $model->number  = 0;
            $model->remove  = 1;
            $model->level   = 0;
            $model->salary  = 0;

            if (!empty($model->pic->extension)) {
              $name = time() . '.' . $model->pic->extension;
              $model->pic = $name;
              if ($model->save()) {
                $model->img->saveAs('uploads/' . $name);
              }
            }

            var_dump($model->getErrors());
            die();
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: error : username and password not empty

Comment: check  `$insert` content.

Comment: where you get the error .. update the question with the exact error message .. and position

Comment: you should be use afterSave  no beforSave

Comment: The best way for solving this question is using of transaction.you can change default save function for that

Comment: Where are you saved data into user table?

Comment: yes,save data into table user and table student.than in form student stay on filed username and password